# Environment variables in Compose using Powershell with only 1 line

Tags: powershell, docker-compose, powershell-5.0

I know that you can pass environment variables to docker-compose.

docker-compose.yml

```
. . .
mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.2
    ports:
     - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
. . .
```

`$ DB_PORT=3396 docker-compose up`

However this only works using bash.  I am using PowerShell and am trying to find an equivalent that is only a one line command.

`PS> $env:DB_PORT:3306 docker-compose up` does not work.  Neither does 
multiline

```
$env:DB_PORT=3396 `
>> docker-compose -up
```

The error I get is 
`Unexpected token 'docker-compose' in expression or statement.`

If I do it one at a time it does work...

```
PS> $env:DB_PORT=3396
PS> docker-compose -up
```

Is there not way to do this in PowerShell when the equivalent in bash is ridiculously simple?

Comment: use the newline characters ``'`r`n'``?

Comment: Are you just trying to put two commands on the same line? If so, use `;` to separate them e.g. `$env:DB_PORT=3396; docker-compose -up`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**POSIX-like shells** such as `bash` offer a way to **set environment variables in a *command-scoped* way, simply by prepending `<varName>=<value>` pairs** directly to a command, as the following example demonstrates:

```
$ foo=bar bash -c 'echo "[$foo]"'; echo "[$foo]"
[bar]
[]
```

`foo=bar` defines *environment* variable `foo` for the `bash -c '...'` *child process* only; the *next* command - `echo ...` - does *not* see this variable.

---

**PowerShell** has **NO equivalent construct** as of v7.4.

To add **support in the future** with at least similar syntax is the subject of a **long-standing feature request**, [GitHub issue #3316](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3316).

For now, the best you can do is to **define the environment variable of interest *first*, in a *separate statement*, using `;`**, PowerShell's statement separator. Any external utility you invoke thereafter - which invariably runs in a *child process* - will see it, but note that **the environment variable will remain in effect in the current PowerShell session, unless you manually remove it**:

```
# Set the env. variable, call the command that should see it,
# remove it afterwards.
PS> $env:foo = 'bar'; bash -c 'echo "[$foo]"'; $env:foo = $null
[bar]
```

Note how `$env:foo = $null` i.e., setting the environment variable to `$null` is the same as *removing* it; alternatively, you could all `Remove-Item env:foo`

If you also want to **restore a pre-existing value afterwards**:

```
$env:foo = 'original'

# Temporarily change $env:foo to a different value, invoke the
# program that should see it, then restore the previous value.
& { $org, $env:foo = $env:foo, 'bar'; bash -c 'echo "[$foo]"'; $env:foo = $org }

$env:foo
```

The above yields:

```
[bar]
original
```

showing that while the `bash` process saw the temporary value, `bar`, the original value of `$env:foo` was restored afterwards.

---

Also note another important difference:

- In *POSIX-like shells*, *environment* variables are implicitly surfaced as *shell* variables - they share the one and only namespace the shell has for variables.
- By contrast, *PowerShell* surfaces environment variables *only* via the `$env:<varName>` namespace (e.g., `$env:foo`), which is distinct from the (prefix-less) namespace for PowerShell's own variables (e.g., `$foo`).